# Cant position div within another div

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem that has been bothering me. I have only 3 things - navigation bar, background, and a random button that I want to place. I have tried 2 things - putting the DIV with the button in the DIV with the background (which I think is right), and putting it in separate DIV.

This is that I want to achieve:

[image]

Instead the Button goes:

[image]

I have tried margin, doesn't do a thing. Also i needn't it to be in position absolute, since it goes over the navigation bar when I scroll.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a><img src="images/button1.png"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="images/button2.png"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="images/button3.png"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="images/button4.png"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="images/button5.png"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="images/button6.png"></a></li>  
</ul>

<div class="back1">
  <div class="returnbutton">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: -5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/rep.png");
  text-align: center;
  height: 47px;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav img {
  height: 47px;
}

.back1 {
  height: 550px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  background-image: url("images/galleryback1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #c4c5c6;
  background-position: center;
}

.returnbutton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: You want "button" to be fixed at that position??

Comment: I don't see any attempts to position the button anywhere, so it ends up in the top left corner of its parent, partially hidden by the fixed nav bar.

Comment: No I do not need it in fixed position. 

I have tried lots of ways, why should i leave empty values in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `div.returnbutton {position: absolute;}` and `#nav {z-index: 99;}`.

The z-index declaration is needed to put the navigation bar over all. So you have to set it more than other z-index that are 0 by default.

I hope helped you.

Comment: This only helps if you also set the left and top properties; otherwise it will still be in the same spot.

Comment: I dont need it in position absolute, It will go over my navigation bar when I scroll.